# Xelement attribute value loses its encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, xelement

Suppose we have this code:

```
string actualvalue = "&lt;a&gt;";
string abc = "<firstnode><secondnode abc=\""+ actualvalue + "\"></secondnode></firstnode>";

XElement item2 = XElement.Parse(abc);
foreach (var item in item2.Descendants("secondnode"))
{
     string aftergettingitfromXlement = item.Attribute("abc").Value;
     ///so aftergettingitfromXlement  = "<a>" which is not correct i want to have actual value which is encoded 
}
```

Any idea how can I get the actual value, I don't want to encode again. Why is the encoding lost?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
string actualvalue = "&amp;lt;a&amp;gt;";
```

The `XDocument` implemenation assumes that the value in your xml string is escaped.
To read more about escpae characters in xml: [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents)

To do a general replace of ampersands in a string you could write:

```
string actualvalue = "&lt;a&gt;";
actualvalue = actualvalue.Replace("&", "&amp;");
```